# Need help on connecting django to react using nginx and gunicorn

Tags: django, reactjs, nginx, gunicorn

I'm trying to connect Django back-end to a React build provided to me by the front-end developer. I'm using Gunicorn for Django and Web server is Nginx.
The below config file is a result of extensive Googling. 
Currently Django back-end works on port 80/8000 but whenever I change the port to anything else like 8001 below, the server does not respond.

The complete thing is running on Google Ubuntu VM.
I've executed `sudo ufw disable` for testing purposes.

```
server {
    #listen 80;
    listen 8001;
    listen [::]:8001;
    server_name xx.xx.7.xx;

    location = /favicon.ico {
        access_log off;
        log_not_found off;
    }

    location /static/ {
        root /home/username/cateringm;
    }

    location / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/run/gunicorn.sock;
    }
    #location / {
     #   try_files $uri $uri/cm_react_build/build/index.html; # this is where you serve the React build
   # }
}
server {
    listen 8002;
    listen [::]:8002;
    server_name xx.xx.7.xx;
    root /home/username/cm_react_build/build;
    index index.html index.htm;

    location /static/ {
        root /home/username/cm_react_build/build;
    }

    location /test {
    root /home/username/cm_react_build/build;
    index index.html;

        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html?$args;
    }
}
```

I'm new to configuring web servers. Help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. Google by default blocks all ports except port 80. I updated the firewall rules for different ports and the requests were going through.